# The MLE's for $(\beta ,\sigma^2)$ in Box-Cox transformation

Tags: inference, boxcox-transformation

Assume that $y=(y_1 ,\ldots ,y_n)$, $y_i >0$. The Box-Cox transformation is
$$y(\lambda ) :=\begin{cases}\frac{y^\lambda-1}{\lambda}&\lambda \neq 0\cr \ln y&\lambda =0\end{cases}.$$

In Box-Cox transformation, it is assumed that $y(\lambda )\sim N(X\beta ,\sigma^2 I_n)$, where $X$ is the design matrix, $y$ is the raw data, and $(\lambda ,\beta ,\sigma^2)$ are the model parameters.

By [https://www.ime.usp.br/~abe/lista/pdfm9cJKUmFZp.pdf](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eabe/lista/pdfm9cJKUmFZp.pdf) the density for the $y(\lambda)$ imply as following: $$f(y(\lambda))=\frac{\exp{\left[-\frac{\left(\mathbf y(\lambda)-\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta\right)^\mathsf T\left(\mathbf y(\lambda)-\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta\right)}{2\sigma^2}\right]}}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}}$$ and then the density for $y$ (which is also the likelihood for the whole model) is $$L(\lambda ,\beta ,\sigma^2 ;y,X)=\frac{\exp{\left[-\frac{\left(\mathbf y(\lambda)-\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta\right)^\mathsf T\left(\mathbf y(\lambda)-\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta\right)}{2\sigma^2}\right]}}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}}J(\lambda ,y)$$ where $J(\lambda ,y)$ is be the Jacobian of the transformation from $y$ to $y(\lambda)$.

The author said that: to obtain the MLE from the last likelihood equation, we observe that for each fixed $\lambda$, the likelihood equation is proportional to the likelihood equation for estimating $(\beta ,\sigma^2)$ for observed $y(\lambda)$. Thus the MLE's for $(\beta ,\sigma^2)$ are $$\tilde{\beta}(\lambda)=(X^TX)-X^Ty(\lambda)$$ and $$\hat{\sigma^2}=\frac{y(\lambda)^T(I_n -G)y(\lambda)}{n}.$$
I would really appreciate if someone could explain me how the author obtained $\tilde{\beta}(\lambda)$ and $\hat{\sigma^2}$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: $J(\lambda,y) = \left| \frac{\partial y_{i}^{\lambda}}{\partial y_{i}} \right| = \prod_{i}^{n} y^{\lambda-1}$ and thus $\log J = (\lambda -1) \sum_{i}^{n} \log y_{i}$ in the log-likelihood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this approach seems unnecessarily complicated. Why not form the likelihood based on the transformed responses (which are normally distributed)? The MLEs result immediately. (Note: The MLE for $\beta$ is missing a transpose on the third $X$.)

If you insist on calculating the MLEs based on the likelihood for the responses on their original scale, note that the Jacobian is constant with respect to both $\beta$ and $\sigma$. Therefore, it can be ignored when calculating the MLEs (it will disappear if you find the log likelihood and then differentiate). The rest of the likelihood has the usual form when the responses are normally distributed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understood and I did what you said and got the result. Just one more question: what is the role of $X$ here? What does it mean? We have our data $y$ and we assume that $y(\lambda)$ has a normal distribution. So where does $X$ come from?

Comment: $X$ is the design matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix).  If you have no predictor variables, $X$ would just be an $n$-dimensional vector of 1's.